# How to run a google apps script using a service account from google cloud platform?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-chat

I'm currently working on a google chatbot and it works with google apps script and google cloud platform.
(Click on this link to see more : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oi3OWHh6Ic).
I manage to run the bot and execute commands with it.
But I want the script that run the chatbot to be execute by a service account when another user execute a command and check for specific values in a spreadsheet.
As I am a beginner with google cloud platform, I search for tutorials that explains how to setup service account. I manage to found one explaining how to setup a service account for google apps script, here : https://daubejb.medium.com/how-to-use-gcp-service-accounts-with-google-apps-script-projects-to-automate-actions-in-g-suite-7020a520bef7.
When I try to call the "getOAuthService(user)" function (coming from the previous url), I got an issue in the google cloud console error journal.

[image: The error i'm getting on google cloud platform]

What could I do next to run the google script with a service account?
(here is my google apps script)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script I use to authenticate a service account in an Apps Script set up on a Google Cloud Project.  It assumes that the JSON file for your Service Account is stored in GoogleDrive.  The included scopes are the ones I used for my project but you would need to add any/all that you need in addition to those.

```js
// Script to authenticate a Google Service Account to use it in an API request.  

function doGet() {
  Logger.log("Function started");
}

// This function identifies the location of the Service Account JSON File.  "Your File ID" applies to if the file is located in Google Drive.  

function getServiceAccountJson() {
  var fileId = '<XXXX>'; // Your file's ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var jsonString = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  return JSON.parse(jsonString);
}

function getAccessToken() {
  var serviceAccount = getServiceAccountJson();
  var privateKey = serviceAccount.private_key;
  var CLIENT_EMAIL = "<XXXXXX>"; // Add in your Service Account email here
  var TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
  var SCOPES = [  
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',          // This is just an exhaustive list of scopes I used across this project, you can include/exclude based on your own needs
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage',
    'https://businessprofileperformance.googleapis.com'
  ];

  var header = {
    "alg": "RS256",
    "typ": "JWT"
  };

  var claimSet = {
    "iss": CLIENT_EMAIL,
    "scope": SCOPES.join(' '),
    "aud": TOKEN_URL,
    "exp": Math.floor((new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000) / 1000),
    "iat": Math.floor((new Date().getTime()) / 1000)
  };
  
  var toSign = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(JSON.stringify(header)) + "." + Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(JSON.stringify(claimSet));
  var signature = Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(toSign, privateKey);
  var jwt = toSign + "." + Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(signature);

  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    "payload": {
      "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
      "assertion": jwt
    }
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(TOKEN_URL, options);
  return JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}

function testServiceAccountAuthentication() {
  var tokenData = getAccessToken();
  
  if (tokenData.access_token) {
    Logger.log("Successfully authenticated. Access token acquired.");
    Logger.log("Access Token: " + tokenData.access_token);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Authentication failed. No access token was acquired.");
    Logger.log(tokenData);
  }
}
```